# keep session in node.js with proxy

Tags: session, authentication, proxy, odata

I wish to connect to site (E) and within an html page access to my odata-server using odata protocol.
I've create a proxy in site (E):

```
    this.use('/data', function(req, res) {
      var request = require('request');
      var apiUrl = process.env.ODATA_SERVER || 'http://localhost:5000';
      url = apiUrl + req.url;
      response = req.pipe(request(url))
      response.pipe(res);
    });
```

this is the scenario: A user connect to site (E), login and a dynamic page should load data from odata-server.

But the problem is: as the browser receive the data I lose the authenticate session with the user and E. How can I keep user login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added this in my authenticate function:

```
(request({uri: uri, jar: true })).auth(loginName, password, false);
```

and now it works! :)

UPDATE: see my last comment :)

Comment: a better solution is to set jar with a custom jar using j = request.jar(); and set cookie j.setCookie(cookie, uri, cb);

Comment: it works setting jar with the cookie received by the odata-server